# Log minified JavaScript errors in production code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am running a back-end app with a React JS frontend on our intranet. I don't want to use services like Sentry or Rollbar to keep track of minified code in production because I don't want to upload our source-maps externally.

Are there any self-hosted solutions for tracking & logging errors in JS source-maps?

Comment: In ReactJs16 u can use error boundary and store and manage ur logs using implements a custom log service etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using a combination of [JSNLog](http://jsnlog.com/) and [Stacktrace](https://www.stacktracejs.com/). This is what goes into the `<head>` of your index.html:

```
<script src="~/js/jsnlog.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/stacktrace.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/stacktraceConfig.js"></script>
```

And below the contents of **stacktraceConfig.js**:

```
window.onerror = function (msg, file, line, col, error) {
    var callback = function (stackframes) {
        var stringifiedStack = stackframes.map(function (sf) {
            return sf.toString();
        }).join('\n');
        JL('serverLog').fatalException({
            msg: 'Exception! ' + stringifiedStack,
            1: '--------------------------------------------------------------',
            errorMsg: msg,
            url: stackframes[0].fileName + ":" + stackframes[0].lineNumber,
            functionName: stackframes[0].functionName,
            lineNumber: stackframes[0].lineNumber,
            column: stackframes[0].column,
            x: '--------------------------------------------------------------',
        }, error);
    };
    var errback = function (err) { console.log(err.message); };

    StackTrace.fromError(error).then(callback).catch(errback);

    // Tell browser to run its own error handler as well
    return false;
};
```

You will have to configure JSNLog yourself to have it send the errors by mail.